# What is the best way to dockerize Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I want to customize *JVM options* and *application command line arguments* when I run dockerized Spring Boot application as example below:

```
java -Xms128M -Xmx256M -jar application.jar --spring.application.name=AcmeApplication
```

What is the best way to construct ENTRYPOINT?

```
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c", "java -jar /application.jar"]
```

Comment: There are many ways.  The "best" way is a matter of opinion, and questions like that are off-topic

Comment: Can not pass command line arguments! Topics you gave do not resolve the problem!

Comment: A number of the methods in the linked Q&A's **show** you how to pass arguments.  Perhaps you had better explain (in your Question) specifically why they are not applicable to your particular use-case.

Comment: Here you may need: [https://medium.freecodecamp.org/docker-entrypoint-cmd-dockerfile-best-practices-abc591c30e21]